# Nancy Ninject Module Construction

Tags: c#, ninject, inversion-of-control, nancy

I'm trying to test my Nancy modules using Ninject as the IoC container. My problem is that I cannot seem to get Nancy to use my IoC bindings to resolve the NancyModule type.

I am using the latest Nancy on Nuget, the latest Nancy.Bootstrap.Ninject built from source with the latest Ninject.

My test setup is as follows:

```
[TestFixtureSetUp]
    public virtual void ClassSetup()
    {
        Assembly.Load(typeof (MyModule).Assembly.FullName);
        var bootstrapper = new AspHostConfigurationSource();
        this.host = new Browser(bootstrapper);
    }

[Test]
public void test()
{
/*snip */
    var id = entity.Id;

    var response = host.Put("/path/to/{0}/".With(id.Encode()),
            (with) =>
            {
                with.HttpRequest();
                with.Header("Accept", "application/xml");
            });

        response.StatusCode.Should().Be(Nancy.HttpStatusCode.OK);

            /*snip */
    }
```

That's my test setup, snipped. Now is my host setup (defined in my assembly):

```
public class MyBootstrapper: Nancy.Bootstrappers.Ninject.NinjectNancyBootstrapper
{
    public bool ApplicationContainerConfigured { get; set; }

    public Ninject.IKernel Container
    {
        get { return ApplicationContainer; }
    }

    public bool RequestContainerConfigured { get; set; }

    protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(Ninject.IKernel existingContainer)
    {
        this.ApplicationContainerConfigured = true;
        base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(existingContainer);

        Nancy.Json.JsonSettings.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
        StaticConfiguration.DisableCaches = true;
    }

    protected override void ConfigureRequestContainer(Ninject.IKernel container, NancyContext context)
    {
        container.Load(new[] { new ServiceModule() });
    }

    protected override DiagnosticsConfiguration DiagnosticsConfiguration
    {
        get { return new DiagnosticsConfiguration { Password = @"12345" }; }
    }
}
```

My IoC bindings are as follows:

```
Bind<Nancy.NancyModule>()
        .ToMethod(context =>
        {
            return new MyModule1(context.Kernel.Get<IMongoRepository<Guid, Entity>>(
                Properties.Settings.Default.NamedCollection1),
                                                  context.Kernel.Get<IMongoRepository<Guid, Entity>>(
                                                    Properties.Settings.Default.NamedCollection2));
        })
        .Named(typeof(MyModule1).FullName);

Bind<Nancy.NancyModule>()
        .ToMethod(context =>
        {
            return new MyModule2(context.Kernel.Get<IMongoRepository<Guid, Entity>>(
                Properties.Settings.Default.NamedCollection3),
                                                  context.Kernel.Get<IMongoRepository<Guid, Entity>>(
                                                    Properties.Settings.Default.NamedCollection4));
        })
        .Named(typeof(MyModule2).FullName);
```

I want to take control of the construction on the Nancy modules. I've looked through the source for Nancy and it looks like for requests nancy asks the configured IoC container for all registered bindings for the type NancyModule with the appropriate key. Code that follows is defined in the Nancy.Bootstrappers.Ninject assembly

```
   protected override sealed NancyModule GetModuleByKey(IKernel container, string moduleKey)
    {
        return container.Get<NancyModule>(moduleKey);
    }
```

The key looks to be generated using a key generator object:

```
public class DefaultModuleKeyGenerator : IModuleKeyGenerator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a string key for the given type
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="moduleType">NancyModule type</param>
    /// <returns>String key</returns>
    public string GetKeyForModuleType(Type moduleType)
    {
        return moduleType.FullName;
    }
}
```

This is why my bindings are set up as named bindings. The idea is that when Nancy requests a named binding (for a module) it will pick p my named bindings.

It is not working as expected. Ninject is complaining that I have multiple bindings setup for the type NancyModule.

To reiterate: my goal is to take control of Nancy module construction.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. When I talk about injecting dependecies into a module I do /not/ refer to NinjectModules as [this question does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022062/how-to-inject-an-object-into-a-ninject-module)

Comment: Not quite sure what you are doing here. The MyBootstrapper type, is that code in your test assembly or in your main Nancy assembly?

Comment: That's the code in my bootstrapper assembly

Comment: I came up with a solution to my problem. I'm not sure if its the optimal solution or whether it is "hackish" but here it is:

In my IoC bindings I can do the following

Unbind<Nancy.NancyModule>();

This deregisters any bindings previously setup by Nancy and allows me to take control of module creation.

If there are no better answers I'll move this to the answer.

Comment: You could just use the configurable bootstrapper, for your tests, which lets you get fine grained control of the bootstrapper setup for each test

Comment: It's documented here https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Testing-your-application and I created an issue for Nancy.Testing polishing here https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/633